# SignIn Google con autentificacion en Firebase

Tags: firebase

Estoy tratando de hacer un SignIn con Google y que autentifique con Firebase pero no lo consigo, os paso el código para ver si me podeis ayudar:

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {

                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(this, "e null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(CAPublicarOfertaActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Si teneis alguna duda preguntad que os respondo rápido

Comment: cual es el problema que te genera ese codigo ?

Comment: el resultcode me lo pilla como cero y eso hace que en el try and catch pille e como null y dando como resultado que el usuario nunca se llegue a loguear en la aplicación